# How to delete all managed objects from to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data

Is it a way to remove all managed object from to-many relationship with one line code, without looping managed object? Is this below "nice" solution?

```
u.cars = NSMutableOrderedSet()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the KVC method `mutableSetValue` of `NSObject`

```
u.mutableSetValue(forKey: "cars").removeAllObjects()
```

or if `cars` is an ordered set

```
u.mutableOrderedSetValue(forKey: "cars").removeAllObjects()
```